# ng-If and ng-message not working in yii

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, yii

I am a new user to Yii and angular. I tried `ng-messages` and `ng-if` in my code below:

```
    <div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'jobTitle', array('placeholder'=>'JobTitle (eg. Trainee)','ng-model'=>'form.jobTitle','name'=>"jobTitle",'required'=>'required'?> <span class="errorMessage mandatory-star">*</span>

    <div ng-messages="jobpost-form.jobTitle.$error" ng-if="interacted(jobpost-form.jobTitle)">
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'organizationName',array('placeholder'=>'Company (eg. Microsoft)',"name"=>"Company",'required'=>'required')); ?> <span class="errorMessage mandatory-star">*</span>

    <div ng-messages="jobpost-form.Company.$error" ng-if="interacted(jobpost-form.Company)">
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton( 'Post Job',array( 'class'=>'btn highlight-btn bigsize')); ?></div>
```

But when I run this into browser the `ng-message` div is disappeared and `ng-If` code is automatically commented. I have seen this in inspect element.

like this:

```
<span class="errorMessage mandatory-star">*</span>
<!-- ngIf: interacted(jobpost-form.jobTitle) -->
```

Comment: How does your `interacted()` look like?

Comment: I defined this function in my controller.                                                                      $scope.interacted = function(field) {
      return $scope.submitted || field.$dirty;
    };

Comment: but why are you using AngularJs with Yii? as far as I know you can use AngularJs as static html files and use a php framework just as a API to store/retrieve data, are you following any tutorial or something?